# Why is arc length defined on a closed interval?

Tags: differential-geometry

My differential geometry text defined a curve as a function from an open interval of $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R^3$, but it defines arc length as the integral in terms of the velocity along a closed interval. Why "closed"? Would the velocity not be well-defined if we used an open interval?

Comment: Consider the path $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(t) = (t, t,1/t)$.  What would its arclength be?

Comment: Riemann integrals are generally defined for a function defined on a closed interval. This to avoid problems like the on given by @Randall. It’s just a definition.